# How to add another project to Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

Does anyone know how to add a project? I faced with problem. I don't know exactly how to add project to sonarqube. I will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a project to your instance of SonarQube, just analyze it and it should appear on the dashboards right after analysis (this requires that you have the global "Execute Analysis" permission).

If you wish to have an Open Source project appear on [the SonarQube public instance on Nemo](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/), please send an email to the [SonarQube Users mailing list](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/).